# Putting 0 at a string to make it of some length in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column named Code filled up with TEXT values as:

```
Code
-------
1111
23456
212
954737
323
1234567
```

Given a natural number `n > 0`: For every row with

```
LENGHT(Code) < n
```

I need to concatenate 0 to the left of Code to get a new string with size  n.

Example:

If  n = 7  for the previous values I need to get

```
0001111
0023456
0000212
0954737
0000323
1234567
```

Using psql... is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be storing numbers as string

Comment: This is not the main point of the question. It is not how I stored the  codes. This the way those codes arrived to me,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this function

```
LPAD(Code::text, 7, '0')
```